# Why should I learn COM?

Tags: com

Lately I'm hearing much about COM at my work. I also learnt that "COM is old. COM is deprecated. There is no future for COM." Are these true, too?

I want to learn COM because I want to know what is the big fuss about it, but I'm unable to convince myself that this is a solid reason for spending so much time and learning it.

So, can any one tell me:

1. Why should I learn COM?
2. Once I learn COM what applications can I use it for?

Comment: Have you ever used MS Word and placed a picture in the document? If so, you are using COM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just don't see COM going away any time soon. If you want to be a windows expert, you must understand how it works.

Answer (score 5):

You should learn enough about COM to know that you don't want to learn any more.

The details of COM - particularly from a multithreaded or C++ application - are excruciatingly irritating, and I would not wish them on anyone (I don't know them myself, but I know enough to  know this).

Therefore if you do need to call a COM library, you should learn enough COM to be able to do so, then stop. Ideally, use a language such as C# or Delphi where some (or hopefully most) of the details are handled for you relatively transparently.

There are a lot of COM libraries around, but if you feel you want to use one, you should look at its specific documentation for how to do this - it probably has a reasonable example that you can simply adapt for your own use without too much effort. If it does not, then it clearly isn't very good and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Excruciatingly irritating sounds hyperbolic to me. COM apartments (I'm assuming that is what youre getting at from the multi-threaded comment) and marshalling aren't _that_ complex, especially if you take the time to read the right resources. Plus, in C++ you can use the ATL as an abstraction layer to hide most of the boilerplate stuff.

Comment: Fair enough, maybe I was overstating it. But it's still nicer to not have to worry about them :)

Answer (score 4):

Learning COM (or at least being *au fait* with its concepts) means you can integrate with thousands of existing components, including Microsoft Word and Excel.

I work largely in the Java domain, but having a little knowledge of COM means I can interface effectively to Word and Excel (in particular) to programatically create/read documents. I don't have an in depth knowledge, but I have a little, and having that increases my productivity substantially.

Answer (score 4):

COM is definitely worth learning to at least some level if you are a Windows developer. Another common case for its use, in addition to the others already mentioned, is in the implementation of [binary behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa744100%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [BHOs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250436%28VS.85%29.aspx) for Internet Explorer. They are both implemented using COM interfaces between IE and your code.

I'd also like to recommend a couple of resources for learning about COM:

1. Don Box's [Essential COM](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kfRWvKSePmAC&dq=don+box+essential+com&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=4DouS_mdLdGL4Qa6o5mYCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false). It is an excellent description of why COM is the way it is and really helps you get a deeper understanding of what is going on. If you take the time to read this book, then you will have a fundamental understanding of COM internals that will serve you very well.
2. These two articles: { [1](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/apts/article.php/c5529), [2](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/apts/article.php/c5533.) } ...are a very good discussion of the particular subject of COM apartments, alluded to as "excruciatingly irritating" (unfairly, imho) in MarkR's answer.

Comment: The first chapter of Essentail COM gives a great overview of what problem COM is trying to solve - it's definelty worth reading even if you skim the rest of the book.